# Reporting Service for Amazon RDS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, amazon-rds

I'm curious if anyone has any leads for me on this:

I have a business app that we're building, that could benefit from some out of the box reporting services.  Looking for reports that can be created and customized by the end user, without (too much) developer support.  Think crystal reports / MS Access reports, but better and all web based interface.

Ideally, this would be a SAAS that I could buy, and that could hook directly up to my Amazon RDS instance.  Then I would create frames around it within my business app for the end users.

I don't want to write my own reporting system - but I need it to be in the cloud to work with my system.  Or be something I could install on a rails app.

So far, all I've found are brochure pages for services I've never heard of or developer solutions for rails on github.  (meaning they have great report creation tools, but no front-ends for users.)

If anyone has any leads, or experience in this, I'd be happy to hear it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of data you're trying to report?

Answer (score 0):

[Docmosis.com](http://docmosis.com)

This is a cloud based reporting system developed for exactly this problem. It uses either Word or Open Office templates that can be edited and maintained by the end user with little or no developer support. There is a front end interface for the user to manage and upload their templates. Changes to the templates are reflected in report output instantly. Once deployed, your application simply calls the web service with the data to inject into the report (JSON, XML) which is then delivered back in a variety of formats including pdf, doc, html.

We have used this in the education sector for some time and found that it saves us a lot of time because the business owners can take on the task of developing the report formats in familiar MS Word and they prefer it that way.

I also know of a developer who has built an iPad app over it too. Docmosis streams pdfs back to the device and emails a copy to a specified email address. You can integrate it from most environments.